# Problems using pip to install packages on Pypy

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, pip, pypy

I want to use Pypy to run a set of data transformations faster, but I need numpy installed so that the script runs unchanged (obviously I could change the script but that's not the point). I tried using pip as the docs told me to, but it just won't work. It gives me an error about not having Visual Studio 14.1, which I do have theoretically (I installed as many redistributables as you can think of, including the 2017 version, which is the same 14.1 as far as I can tell).

I'm also aware of the possibility of downloading the module and executing the setup or cloning it from github, but getting pip to work would be nice as I'm interested in downloading quite a few of them in the near future.

Still, I'm very noobish when it comes to Windows, so I'll be glad if you have any idea of why it isn't working.

This is the error and log I get from Windows Shell:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>pypy3 -m ensurepip
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>pypy3 -m pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/d6/be8f975f5322336f62371c9abeb936d592c98c047ad63035f1b38ae08efe/numpy-1.17.3.zip
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Running setup.py install for numpy ... error
    Complete output from command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Pypy\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\pypy3.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\alefe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-uvuig992\\numpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\alefe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-xm3lustt\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Running from numpy source directory.

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)


    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Pypy\\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries blis not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Pypy\\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
    customize MSVCCompiler
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Pypy\\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\\libs']
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize PGroupFlangCompiler
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Pypy\\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Pypy\\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Pypy\\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Pypy\\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\alefe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uvuig992\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      self.calc_info()
    blas_info:
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries blas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Pypy\\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\alefe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uvuig992\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\alefe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uvuig992\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    'svnversion' nÆo \u201a reconhecido como um comando interno
    ou externo, um programa oper vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Pypy\\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
    customize MSVCCompiler
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Pypy\\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
    customize MSVCCompiler
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Pypy\\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    flame_info:
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries flame not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Pypy\\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Pypy\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\libs
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Pypy\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Pypy\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\libs
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Pypy\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Pypy\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\libs
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Pypy\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Pypy\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\libs
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Pypy\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Pypy\\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\alefe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uvuig992\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\alefe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uvuig992\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Pypy\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running config_cc
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    running config_fc
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win32-3.6
    creating build\src.win32-3.6\numpy
    creating build\src.win32-3.6\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.1 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Pypy\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\pypy3.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\alefe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-uvuig992\\numpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\alefe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-xm3lustt\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\alefe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uvuig992\numpy\
```

**Upgrade:**
I managed to install sympy using pip without any problems. I could also install numpy using the method described by mattip. Still, most packages keep giving me the Microsoft Visual error or a similar one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pip can install either a binary compiled package or can download and compile the source code of the package. But it cannot compile from source without a compiler. Either

- install the compiler and learn to build c-extension modules from source (not recommended)

or

- always use `pip install --only-binary :all: <package>` to force pip to fail if there is no binary

You can find binary wheels for windows at https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy, you need the ones that have a pp372 in the name (pp for PyPY, 3 for python 3, 72 for pypy 7.2.x)

Comment: But how is it so that pypy's documentation suggests the use of pip then? Again, sorry for the ignorance.

Comment: Forgot to put the links. As in http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/install.html or http://pypy.org/download.html#installing-more-modules

Comment: the documentation assumes you are using an operating system that supports compilation. Unfortunately you are not on such an operating system.