# Problem installing numpy for PyPy3 on Windows 10

Tags: python, visual-studio, numpy, pip, pypy

I am having issues trying to install numpy for pypy3 on my Windows 10 machine.

As I am unable to tell if this problem stems from my pypy3 installation or from something else I am describing here all the steps that I have followed so far:

As indicated on the official [download page](https://www.pypy.org/download.html#python-3-6-compatible-pypy3-6-v7-3-1) I have:

- downloaded and installed the "Visual C++ Redistributable Package" `vcredist.x86.exe`
- downloaded and installed the Pypy3 "Windows binary (32 bits)" file `pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32.zip`

Then after having manually added pypy3 to the `PATH` of my machine, I have:

- installed the `pip` package from the shell with the command `pypy3 -m ensurepip`

The problem arises when trying to install numpy. The official [documentation](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/faq.html#what-about-numpy-numpypy-micronumpy) says that one can install it by doing `pypy -m pip install numpy` (`pypy3` in my case) but doing so throws the following error:

```
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.18.4.zip (5.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\pypy3\pypy3.exe' 'C:\pypy3\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\solub\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplva52crq'
         cwd: C:\Users\solub\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fe1jhyy5\numpy
    Complete output (231 lines):
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_bit_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
    Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
    Cythonizing sources
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
      libraries blis not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3\\libs']
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize PGroupFlangCompiler
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    flame_info:
      libraries flame not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\pypy3\libs
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\pypy3\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\pypy3\libs
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\pypy3\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\pypy3\libs
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\pypy3\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\pypy3\libs
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\pypy3\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    running dist_info
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win32-3.6
    creating build\src.win32-3.6\numpy
    creating build\src.win32-3.6\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    Running from numpy source directory.
    setup.py:461: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    C:\Users\solub\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fe1jhyy5\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\solub\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fe1jhyy5\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\solub\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fe1jhyy5\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\solub\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fe1jhyy5\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1730: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    C:\Users\solub\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fe1jhyy5\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1730: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    C:\pypy3\lib-python\3\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\pypy3\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\pypy3\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "C:\pypy3\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "C:\Users\solub\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0puh3yb5\overlay\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 158, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        self.run_setup()
      File "C:\Users\solub\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0puh3yb5\overlay\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 250, in run_setup
        self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
      File "C:\Users\solub\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0puh3yb5\overlay\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 143, in run_setup
        exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
      File "setup.py", line 488, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "setup.py", line 480, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "C:\Users\solub\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fe1jhyy5\numpy\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 171, in setup
        return old_setup(**new_attr)
      File "C:\Users\solub\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0puh3yb5\overlay\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\pypy3\lib-python\3\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\pypy3\lib-python\3\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\pypy3\lib-python\3\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\solub\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0puh3yb5\overlay\site-packages\setuptools\command\dist_info.py", line 31, in run
        egg_info.run()
      File "C:\Users\solub\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fe1jhyy5\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py", line 26, in run
        self.run_command("build_src")
      File "C:\pypy3\lib-python\3\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\pypy3\lib-python\3\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\solub\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fe1jhyy5\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 146, in run
        self.build_sources()
      File "C:\Users\solub\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fe1jhyy5\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 157, in build_sources
        self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
      File "C:\Users\solub\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fe1jhyy5\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 290, in build_library_sources
        sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
      File "C:\Users\solub\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fe1jhyy5\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 380, in generate_sources
        source = func(extension, build_dir)
      File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 661, in get_mathlib_info
        raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
    RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\pypy3\pypy3.exe' 'C:\pypy3\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\solub\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplva52crq' Check the logs for full command output.
```

As suggested in the same document I have also tried to use the experimental [PyPy binary wheels](https://github.com/antocuni/pypy-wheels) with the command:

`pypy3 -m pip install --extra-index-url https://antocuni.github.io/pypy-wheels/manylinux2010 numpy`

but the exact same error message appears. I should note that a similar workaround recommended in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58522969/problems-using-pip-to-install-packages-on-pypy) related thread failed as well.

Additional information:

- I have "Visual Studio Build Tools 2019" installed (MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 Build Tools (v14.25))
- I am using pip version 20.1 along with setuptools version 46.4.0
- I have made English the main language for my system (a possible non-ascii conflict was mentioned in the comments below)
- I have tried with other versions (pypy2.7 v7.3.1 and pypy3.6 v7.3.0) to no avail (same error message)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for trying out PyPy on Windows and reporting problems. We don't really have a large Windows PyPy community, so feedback is good. I think we may have fixed this rpython error after the 7.3.1 release: could you try a nightly build from http://buildbot.pypy.org/nightly/py3.6/pypy-c-jit-latest-win32.zip ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I just tried with the nightly build but to no avail: same message with a slightly different error notification at the end: `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\pypy3\pypy3.exe' 'C:\pypy3\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\solub\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpldtxn3yl' Check the logs for full command output.`

Comment: @mattip It seems some libraries are missing (mkl_rt, blis, openblas...). Could it be that this numpy version is expecting specific libraries available only on a linux system ? Has someone ever succeeded in installing numpy for pypy3 on a windows 10 machine recently ? Sorry for all the questions, I am trying my best to understand how to get around this issue but information is scarce and/or outdated.

Comment: The missing blas, blis, lapack are all warnings. The problem is the interpreter crashes with `File "rpython_rlib.c", line 15063, in _nonascii_unichr_as_utf8_append`. Do you have non-ascii characters in your path or do you use a non-english windows environment?

Comment: In order to build NumPy you must have a MSVC compiler: `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.1 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/`. Do you have that installed?

Comment: Now that I have Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 installed the `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.1 is required` notification has disappeared (question has been updated with the new error message). I do have a non-english windows environment, could it be that I have to reinstall windows in english ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for trying out PyPy on Windows and reporting problems. We don't really have a large Windows PyPy community, so feedback is good. There are two things at play here:

- The RPython error (think of it as a C level segfault in CPython), which might be caused by non-ascii path names. I *think* we fixed this after the 7.3.1 release, but it would be good to try to work out exactly what is going on there, it is/was a bug deep in PyPy.
- The failure to build, with the cryptic "Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program". This has to do with a transition from MSVC9 (Visual Studio 2008) to MSVC14 (Visual Studio 2017, 2019) in the latest release. It should be fixed in [this commit](https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/pypy/commit/1f5925b68f4210fbc5d852b03643c588d45f99a5) to PyPy, which should land in the next nightly build

Comment: pypy/pypy3 version 7.3.2 supports a lot more numpy; please try it out (release candidates: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pypy-dev/2020-September/016023.html)

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be ppy3 is not properly installed. Try installing through wget.

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
./pypy get-pip.py
```

Once installed, try installing numpy

```
pypy -m pip install numpy
```