# How to fix error when installing numpy in pypy with pip?

Tags: python, numpy, pip, pypy

I am trying to set up a pypy Interpreter in my PyCharm IDE.
I am using Windows 10 version 10.0.18363 Build 18363 on a x64 based machine.

I downloaded PyPy 3.6 v7.3.1 on the pypy site (https://www.pypy.org/download.html) in .zip format.
I unzipped it in a new folder on my dektop.
I got a folder with the name "pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32"
In this folder there are a few folders and 2 exe "pypy3" and "pypy3w".
I tried to follow this instruction https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/install.html

In my cmd I went to the directory (desktop\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32) and used `pypy3 -m ensurepip`

```
pypy3 -mpip install -U pip wheel
pypy3 -mpip install numpy
```

It didnt work. I tried updating setuptools, didnt help either.

This is the error I am getting.

```
    Collecting numpy
    Using cached numpy-1.19.2.zip (7.3 MB)
    Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Pypyp\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\pypy3.exe' 'C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Pypyp\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7q2dt_nk'
         cwd: C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ccfq_zfi\numpy
    Complete output (190 lines):
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
    Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
    Cythonizing sources
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Robert\\Desktop\\Pypyp\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
      libraries blis not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Robert\\Desktop\\Pypyp\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

  

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Robert\\Desktop\\Pypyp\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize PGroupFlangCompiler
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Robert\\Desktop\\Pypyp\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Robert\\Desktop\\Pypyp\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Robert\\Desktop\\Pypyp\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Robert\\Desktop\\Pypyp\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Robert\\Desktop\\Pypyp\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Robert\\Desktop\\Pypyp\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Robert\\Desktop\\Pypyp\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Robert\\Desktop\\Pypyp\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    flame_info:
      libraries flame not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Robert\\Desktop\\Pypyp\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Pypyp\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\libs
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Pypyp\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Pypyp\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\libs
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Pypyp\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Pypyp\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\libs
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Pypyp\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Pypyp\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\libs
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Pypyp\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Robert\\Desktop\\Pypyp\\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
      FOUND:
        language = c

    running dist_info
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win32-3.6
    creating build\src.win32-3.6\numpy
    creating build\src.win32-3.6\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    Running from numpy source directory.
    setup.py:470: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ccfq_zfi\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ccfq_zfi\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ccfq_zfi\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ccfq_zfi\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ccfq_zfi\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Pypyp\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.1 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Pypyp\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\pypy3.exe' 'C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\Pypyp\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Loca
\Temp\tmp7q2dt_nk' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I also installed the newest version of Visual C++ 14.x

I tried installing numpy directly through the IDE.
I tried installing other packages some worked (MathLab) others didnt (VTK), but with a different error.

```
DEPRECATION: The -b/--build/--build-dir/--build-directory option is deprecated. pip 20.3 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is use the TMPDIR/TEMP/TMP environment variable, possibly combined with --no-clean. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for vtk
```

On my system there are 2 other Python Interpreters installed Miniconda 3.7 and standard python 3.8.
If I try to uninstall numpy in the other python interpreters I get the error:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed


PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - numpy
```

I am a beginner with Python and I have no clue what to do next except uninstalling every python related thing on my computer and reinstall everything again, but I'd like to avoid that right now.

Do you have any idea how to install numpy?
Any solution how to fix my system or set it up correctly if I did anything wrong would be much appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61841401/problem-installing-numpy-for-pypy3-on-windows-10.  Also, maybe some of the problems have been fixed in the meantime; try to use the very recent release candidate of pypy: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pypy-dev/2020-September/016023.html.

Comment: sorry that I didnt find the already exisiting question. 
The newest version you suggested worked like a charm. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As Armin rodrigo suggested the newest version did the trick.
mail.python.org/pipermail/pypy-dev/2020-September/016023.html
Numpy works right now.